# Automagic way of giving objects an id and referencing it by said id?

Tags: java, refactoring, code-cleanup

Apologies for the rubbish title, if there is a term for this problem, please change it! Thanks.

How can I cleanup the following "pattern" in my code to be more automatic. By this I mean that I can create a new object that extends Foo without having to create a static field member of Foo for the said object and add it to a hashmap.

```
class Foo { 
    protected int id;
    public Foo(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public static final int BAR = 0;
    public static final int QUX = 1;
    public static HashMap<Integer, Foo> FOOS = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        FOOS.put(BAR, new Bar());
        FOOS.put(QUX, new Qux());
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar() { this(Foo.BAR); }
}

class Qux extends Foo {
    public Qux() { this(Foo.QUX); }
}
```

The main requirement I have is that I can easily address each object by it's ID, i.e. no magic numbers:

```
someArray[randomIndex] = Foo.BAR;
```

But they still need to have an integer so that I could place in a random number and it can do a lookup to the object it references to:

```
for (int i : someArray) {
    // for simplicity pretend that all the values
    // in someArray are all valid keys for the FOOS hashmap
    System.out.println(Foo.FOOS.get(i).id);
}
```

Comment: Can you devise a perfect `hashCode()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hackish, but you could use an `enum Foo` which handles the objects and ids:

```
enum Foo {
    QUX;

    private static int idIncrementor = 0;
    private int id;

    Foo() {
        this.id = idIncrementor++;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then embed it within a `FooManager` class, which handles the mapping:

```
class FooManager {
    private static HashMap<Integer, Foo> foos = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for(Foo foo : Foo.values()) {
            foos.put(foo.getId(), foo);
        }
    }

    public static Foo getFoo(int id) {
        return foos.get(id);
    }

    //enum Foo goes here
}
```

You can then add new enums without worrying about mapping them every time.

To access an object, simply do `FooManager.getFoo(#)`.
To find the `id` of an object: `FooManager.Foo.QUX.getId()`.